# Will shrinking a partition destroy all data?

Tags: linux, gparted

I was trying to shrink **60GB** of my partition (**463GB**) to create another partition with ***GParted***. i want to make sure that no data will be lost first. will i lose any data if i shrink the partition?

Comment: The filesystem needs to be shrunk prior to reducing the size if the partitiin. I think gparted can sometimes do this but it will depend on the filsystem in question and if its mounted. Regardless, this is a dangerous operation - back up first.

Comment: The last time I used `gparted` to shrink and move partitions, it automatically adjusted the filesystem (ext4) size, halted with an error if the chosen size was too small to hold the data and even shifted data around within the filesystem to achieve size and position, so the things that one (at least me) cannot do with the usually command line utilities, i.e. `resize2fs -M` in case of ext4. But better to check docs and test first before taking this as definite answer. And a backup is always mandatory ;).

Comment: You may or may no lose data.   Depends on the filesystem type and current filesystem size.   Better to shrink the filesystem first and then the partition.   BTW, some filesystems such as XFS cannot be reduced in size after they are created - you have to backup up the data, destroy the filesytem, created a new smaller filesystem and restore the data to the new filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

***In theory*** you will not lose data.

In practice over the years I have used built-in tools on Windows, `gparted` on Linux, and other third party utilities to shrink or resize partitions on various operating systems and everything has gone well with no data loss.

**But** sometimes things happen, filesystems look fine but might have some odd corruption as power outages happen, structures get updated over the years as software changes slightly and sometimes the shrinking software just chokes, gives up and leaves your disk in a state that is, to put it politely, *Not Good*.

I've even started shrinking a disk in Windows, left it for half an hour, realised I made a critical mistake, tried to cancel, then hard powered off the machine. When powered back on it carried on as if nothing at all had happened and was 100% fine. That I got lucky doesn't make doing this "safe". I was expecting the disk to be toast.

All that said you should be able to shrink a disk without losing everything, that doesn't mean you shouldn't prepare for the worst.

Make sure your backups are good, and know what your strategy for reinstalling is if the worst happens.